# API that will continuously return data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Beginner here, I'm using Firebase real time database and I need my API to constantly return that value when something has been added see my code below.

```
apiCalls.get('/api/getallusers',function(req,res){
  userFunc.getAllUsers(function(err,result){
    if (err) return res.status(500).send('internal server error!');
    res.status(200).write(JSON.stringify(result));
    res.end();
    return res;
  })
})
```

this will return the error

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

but if i remove res.end it will show 1 record and constantly load until the page times out..

is what I'm doing possible or are there different ways to do it.

also I'm using firebase cloud functions for this api.

UPDATE:

Uploaded the API but it does not return anything...

here is the link https://us-central1-testproject-e6819.cloudfunctions.net/api1/api/getUser

tried axios and Event Source

Firebase functions logs the values but it does not return it..

Comment: "but if i remove res.end it will show 1 record and constantly load until the page times out.."  Is that not **exactly what you want**?

Comment: if for example a mobile device connects to that API will that device also experience a time out like that?

Comment: I'm worried that when I access that API in my browser it only shows 1 record but in my terminal log it does return more values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations in Cloud Functions must be relatively short-lived and end deterministically. There is no way to keep a connection open from Cloud Functions to the client.

Typically consider what triggers the need to send new data. For example, if it is triggered by the fact that a new user is registered, you can use [trigger your Cloud Functions from Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). Then the function could for example write to the Realtime Database (or Cloud Firestore), and your client/app listens to the database for realtime updates. That way you're using all the pieces of Firebase in the way they're designed: Cloud Functions for short-lived updates triggered from events in the system, and the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore for sending realtime updates.

If that doesn't work for your use-case, you'll need a runtime environment that allows you to keep processes alive. Something like App Engine flex, Kubernetes, or many other options come to mind for that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's a bummer that it's not possible because I'm planning to pass real time values to a mobile device real time using API's only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're viewing the API response like a web page, your browser is buffering the data it's received until there's enough of it to form a more full page.  Your browser is expecting content that ends, not some endless stream of data.

You *should* remove `.end()` if you expect to be able to continue to write to the output stream.

Also, I recommend using the Server-Sent Events (SSE) protocol for this.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events  It provides a nice standards-based abstraction that makes it very easy to handle event streams client-side.

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('https://api.example.com/someApi');
eventSource.addEventListener('userupdate', (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
});
```

Server-side, there are a couple Express-based middlewares to make this even easier than it already is.

Comment: Thanks! this listener is what I need.

Comment: apparently it returns nothing.. there are logs in my firebase cloud function but it does not return anything in my client here is my link.. https://us-central1-testproject-e6819.cloudfunctions.net/api1/api/getUser

i used that method and also axios.. I'm use react for my client